# Familial ties...!

Tags: riddle

My prefix is good for campaigns

My suffix is found in a bathroom

My infix is Christian

My whole has been associated with the British royalty by some.

What is it?

Hint

> Blizzard

> Cold

> Focus on the suffix first

> Bathroom wall

Comment: Another hint???

Comment: Even with two hints I still have no idea. Is the answer a very obscure word?

Comment: Not at all...my friend

Comment: Words ending in -brush, -bath, -sink, -floss, -rod, -wash, -razor, -can, -comb,-scale, -cream, -water, -shower, -tub, -towel, -paper and -soap all got me nowhere and don't fit royalty or coldness, so I give up. I hope somebody else figures it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be

> Reptile

My prefix is good for campaigns

> **Rep** = short for reputation, which is good for campaigns

My suffix is found in a bathroom

> **Tile** (also found by Johnson)

My infix is Christian

> **PTI** Pastor Training International [PTI](https://www.pastor-training.org/) a Christian organisation (suggested by stiv)

My whole has been associated with the British royalty by some.

> I read on some websites that the queen is an extraterrestrial reptile and that this was even confirmed by the Buckingham Palace. But this might be just some conspiracy theory, I'm not so sure anymore ;)

> Reptiles are cold blooded, that would also match the hints

Comment: Your infix might be [this](https://www.pastor-training.org/)...?

Comment: In fact, I meant with the extra letter on the end as well - it's a Christian organisation, which might be what the OP is alluding to here :)

Comment: Oh, I should have read more than the link name, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: The infix is a t which looks like a cross. But apart from that well done. This puzzle took a lot longer to solve than expected.

Comment: Also the title both pertains to the last clue and to the fact that our anscestors were reptiles.

Answer (score 3):

Is the answer

> Textile(s)?

My prefix is good for campaigns

> Text - A few options for this one - it could be a text message (SMS) marketing campaign, or even a role playing campaign with a lot of lore!

My suffix is found in a bathroom

> Tile(s) - often found on a bathroom wall

My infix is Christian

> X (Cross) - symbol of Christianity

My whole has been associated with the British royalty by some.

> Textiles and tapestries often adorn the castles and palaces of British royalty.

Comment: Close, very close

Comment: Hint: look at the Title!!!

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> Mercantile

My prefix is good for campaigns

> **Merc** = abbreviation of "mercenary"

My suffix is found in a bathroom

> **Tile** (also found by Johnson)

My infix is Christian

> **Canti** = the highest voices in polyphonic choral music.

My whole has been associated with the British royalty by some.

> Possibly a reference to the [Merchant Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merchant_Navy_(United_Kingdom)) as an offshoot of the Royal Navy and imperial expansion.

Comment: Wrong answer, will someone just get this already lol.

Comment: @Deepthinker101 It's common for prefix-suffix-infix puzzles with vaguer clues to have multiple answers that feel correct to a solver but aren't what you intended, so be patient - somebody will get it. (It's also nice to acknowledge that these OPs gave a solid answer even if it's not your intended answer.)